# mysql select datetime query to find ids which are 1 year old, 2 year old and so on

Tags: mysql, sql

I want ids which were created in last 1 year, or year > 1 but year < 2, and so on. Like suppose if this is the table:

```
+----+--------------------------+---------------------+
| id | data                     | cur_timestamp       |
+----+--------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | The time of creation is: | 2014-02-01 20:37:22 |
|  2 | The time of creation is: | 2015-01-01 20:37:22 |
|  3 | The time of creation is: | 2015-02-01 20:37:22 |
|  4 | The time of creation is: | 2015-12-01 20:37:22 |
|  5 | The time of creation is: | 2016-02-01 20:37:22 |
|  6 | The time of creation is: | 2016-04-01 20:37:22 |
+----+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to get a table like this:

```
+-----------------------+-------+
| date range            | count |
+-----------------------+-------+
| last 1 year           | 3     |
| > 1 year & < 2 years  | 2     |
| > 2 years             | 1     |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

Any content in first column is fine. But I would like to have the count as specified above. I have tried various things.

```
select count(*) from ids where cur_timestamp >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 year);
```

This will give me count of ids in last one year. Similarly I can extend it to get the other values. But is there some way by which I can get all the values in one single query?

Comment: Either use UNION with every internal or check for adoption of a solution for rolling sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called conditional aggregation. You have to add more conditions to get as many years needed.

```
select 
count(case when cur_timestamp >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 year) then 1 end) last_1_yr,
count(case when cur_timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 1 year) and cur_timestamp <= date_sub(now(), interval 2 year) then 1 end) bw_1_2_yrs,
count(case when cur_timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 2 year) then 1 end) gt_2_yrs
from ids
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot. Just a couple of minor tweaks in the query at lt/gt sign. 
`select 
count(case when cur_timestamp >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 year) then 1 end) last_1_yr,
count(case when cur_timestamp < date_sub(now(), interval 1 year) and cur_timestamp >= date_sub(now(), interval 2 year) then 1 end) bw_1_2_yrs,
count(case when cur_timestamp < date_sub(now(), interval 2 year) then 1 end) gt_2_yrs
from ids`

Answer (score 0):

This is code:

```
 SELECT DATE(cur_timestamp) as date, COALESCE(count(*),0)  as count FROM ids  
WHERE DATE(cur_timestamp) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 365 DAY GROUP BY DATE(cur_timestamp)
```

try this i will gives you total count from today's date in interval of 365 days. you can change your day interval.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it (untested so please excuse any typos) is the generate a range of timeframes and join that against your ids table.

For example this is to give all the counts, year by year for the last 100 years:-

```
SELECT CONCAT('> ', interval_end, ' year & < ', interval_start, ' year'), COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT tns.acnt * 10 + units.acnt AS interval_end,  
            DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL tns.acnt * 10 + units.acnt YEAR) AS date_range_end,
            tns.acnt * 10 + units.acnt + 1 AS interval_start,
            DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL tns.acnt * 10 + units.acnt + 1 YEAR) AS date_range_start
    FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN ids ON ids.cur_timestamp BETWEEN date_range_end AND date_range_start
GROUP BY CONCAT('> ', interval_end, ' year & < ', interval_start, ' year')
```

Comment: I get an error at `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL sub0.interval_end YEAR) ` which says: ` Unknown column 'sub0.interval_end' in 'field list'`

Comment: @user3515684 - As I said, untested. Hopefully fixed that.